# ERROR ITMS-90360: Missing Info.plist value

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, upload

How do you solve this error? Already my .plist for extension includes

```
NSExtensionPointIdentifier
```

This is the extension .plist but appstore keeps rejecting it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST     1.0//EN""http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension</string>
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
<key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
<string>6.0</string>
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_PACKAGE_TYPE)</string>
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>1.0</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>1</string>
<key>NSExtension</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.usernotifications.service</string>
    <key>NSExtensionPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).NotificationService</string>
</dict>
```

```
ERROR ITMS-90360: Missing Info.plist value. A value for the key NSExtensionPointIdentifier in bundle Runner.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex is required.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved issue. I mistakenly used the wrong code on my onesignalext .plist. I had to delete it and it worked.

Comment: I don't get it. What's exactly wrong about it?

Comment: The value was missing and issue was solved after adding it. You can also choose to delete the key if it is not required.